# Unable to Connect to MarkLogic via ODBC on CentOs

Tags: odbc, marklogic, powerbi

We've got a MarkLogic server running on CentOS with an ODBC endpoint defined. When I attempt to connect to it via Power BI with ODBC, I get the error below.

[image: ODBC Error]

I've got a similar MarkLogic server running locally, and I don't have any issues connecting via ODBC.

Notes:

- Testing the connection using ODBC Data Source Administrator is successful
- MarkLogic running on the CentOS server is version 9ea

There's nothing in the 8052_ErrorLog.txt, however, in the 8052_AccessLog.txt I see this:

```
192.168.21.34 - nickh [23/Mar/2017:09:43:36 -0400] init
192.168.21.34 - nickh [23/Mar/2017:09:43:36 -0400] password
192.168.21.34 - nickh [23/Mar/2017:09:43:36 -0400] query
192.168.21.34 - nickh [23/Mar/2017:09:43:36 -0400] query
192.168.21.34 - nickh [23/Mar/2017:09:43:36 -0400] query
192.168.21.34 - nickh [23/Mar/2017:09:43:36 -0400] query
192.168.21.34 - nickh [23/Mar/2017:09:43:36 -0400] query
192.168.21.34 - nickh [23/Mar/2017:09:43:36 -0400] terminate
```

Comment: Was the ODBC data source set up for the same architecture as the installed version of Power BI (i.e. both x64 or x86)?

Comment: ODBC data source matches the installed version of Power BI (both x64). Tried a 32 bit data source for kicks, but then I get an `architecture mismatch` error.

Comment: Tried 32 bit Power BI with a 32 bit ODBC driver, still get the `Error while executing the query` message from above.

Comment: The ODBC server port is exposed and available to outside connections? I.e. Iptables

Comment: Within MarkLogic, the ODBC port was set to run on 8052. I can both reach that port on the server via telnet, and testing the connection with the ODBC Administrator yields a successful connection test.

Comment: Anything in either /var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/8052_AccessLog.txt or .../8052_ErrorLog.txt?

Comment: Edited question to include this, but I do see lines in the access log (see above), but nothing in the error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a terribly satisfying answer, but this appears to be a known issue with MarkLogic 9ea running on CentOS. According to the MarkLogic support forums:

> Thanks for looking further into this problem. It looks like you’re running into a bug that we discovered and fixed recently – so this ought to work in 9.0-1.
>
> John

https://ea.marklogic.com/forums/topic/odbc-connection-from-excel-doesnt-work/#post-3031 (link requires MarkLogic EA access)

Issue is reported to be fixed for the production release which is expected around May.